# Android: Launch Application on Home button(Or Volume or KeylockButton) Click

Tags: android, android-button

My Application will run on back end..

As soon i click(or Long click) on home button(Or Volume or KeylockButton)... i have to launch my application...

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not recommended.Google would not like you when you go to them submitting your apps

Answer (score 1):

Make your app the home screen. That is the only way to have your app launched when the home button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to override home button of android.